# Student question about compactness of sets

Tags: analysis

I'm just learning about compactness and being confused.

Closed sets are not compact?

Take $[a,b]$ and the covering $\{(a+\frac{b-a}n,b-\frac{b-a}n):n\geq3\}$. There is no finite subcover. $n$ must approach infinity otherwise it doesn't cover $[a,b]$.

I'm probably missing something obvious here.

Comment: The set of intervals you wrote only covers the open interval $(a,b)$.

Comment: No. As a limitpoint, yes, but neither $a$ nor $b$ will be an element of the *union* of these intervals.

Comment: I get it. Dumb mistake, but thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this mean open sets are never compact? Because this applies to open sets.

Comment: Assuming $T_2$ separation ('Hausdorff') --which of course holds in $\Bbb R$-- every compact set is closed.
In $\Bbb R^n$ the compact sets are exactly the *closed, bounded* sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set of intervals you wrote only covers the open interval $(a,b)$.

Anyway, $[a,b]$ is compact, but e.g. a closed ray $[0,+\infty)$ is closed but not compact in $\Bbb R$.

In $\Bbb R^n$ compact sets are just the closed bounded sets.

By the way, your argument perfectly works to show that the open interval $(a,b)$ is not compact.